# Getting an error on my NavAgent script in Unity. IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, unity-game-engine

I am getting an error " IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range. NavAgent.FindDestination()" I am fairly new to C# and I haven't used arrays before so I
am not quite sure what my problem is.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Here's my full script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NavAgent : MonoBehaviour {

NavMeshAgent myNavAgent;

[SerializeField]
PathNode[] myPathNodes;

int navIndex = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    myNavAgent = GetComponent ("NavMeshAgent") as NavMeshAgent;
    navIndex = 0;
    FindDestination ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void FindDestination()
{
    Vector3 newTravelPosition = myPathNodes [navIndex].transform.position;

    myNavAgent.SetDestination (newTravelPosition);
}

void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    ++navIndex;

    if (navIndex >= myPathNodes.Length)
                    navIndex = 0;

    FindDestination ();
}
}
```

Comment: You're not initializing `myPathAgent`

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 newTravelPosition = myPathNodes [navIndex].transform.position;
```

Probably the exception happens on this row. You should initializing myPathNodes. There will be nothing on `myPathNodes[navIndex]`

```
[SerializeField]
PathNode[] myPathNodes; //this will be null.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about your code and aswer one question. Do you know the maximum size of the array before starting the game?

If the answer is yes, you need to initialize the array like this:

```
PathNode[] myPathNodes = new  PathNode[maximumSize];
```

Else, I recommend you to use list instead of array (because list size is assigned dynamically), you can read more about lists in C# here:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Don´t hesitate to comment if you need more help :)